# How can i make a foreground and background 2-3 hr timer in a Swift game?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I have a game that I'm adding a timer when the player loses, of 3 hours for now. When the time passes out, the player can get free 15 coins of my game.

For now, I'm using NSTimer. The problem is that whenever i put the game in background mode, the timer stops as I read in the documentation. So the timing would run only for game playtime and not always.

How can I achieve this? I will even send a Notification to the user when that timer ended so the user can get into my game and grab the coins for free.

Here's what i have so far:

```
var coinCountdown = 10800 // 3hr = 10800
var coinCurrentTimer = NSTimer.init()
var coinCountdownLabel = SKLabelNode()
```

Then in the init of my SKScene I do:

```
self.coinCurrentTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.updateCoinCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And this is the updateCoinCountdown method:

```
func updateCoinCountdown() {
        if(self.coinCountdown > 0){
            var hour = String(self.coinCountdown / 3600)
            var minutes = String((self.coinCountdown % 3600) / 60)
            var seconds = String((self.coinCountdown % 3600) % 60)

            if Int(hour) < 10 {
                hour = "0" + hour
            }

            if Int(minutes) < 10 {
                minutes = "0" + minutes
            }

            if Int(seconds) < 10 {
                seconds = "0" + seconds
            }

            self.coinCountdownLabel.text = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
            self.coinCountdown = self.coinCountdown - 1

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if defaults.valueForKey("coinCountdown") != nil {
                defaults.setValue(self.coinCountdown, forKey: "coinCountdown")
            }

        }else{
            print("Done! Send notification and show get coin button")
        }
    }
```

Any hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: You cannot implement this feature using Timer..Even,Candy crush implemented this feature adding time interval to current time and checking if device time met the time.And user did switch device time to future and hacked it. :)

Comment: Oh :( thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done something like this yet, but I have an idea how it could be done.

When the 'timer' is supposed to start you could schedule a local silent notification that would alert the app that the time has passed or an event has been triggered.

When the app receives this scheduled notification it could run some basic checks to see if anything has happened since the notification was scheduled that may cancel it out, if not then it could trigger an immediate local notification to alert the user of the event.

See the documentation for [Local and remote notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) it even has a reference to an event in which the "TIMER_EXPIRED" which is similar to my suggestion above.

EDIT: Looking over the documentation it doesn't look like you can schedule a silent notification, but in theory this could still work for your case.

Comment: I dont know to be honest. I dont know how the internals of it work. I guess changing the time 2hr 59mins forward would trigger the event in 1 minute. luckily, that wasn't the question the op asked. I 'd say that would be another question and too broad for here. You would likely need to store the trigger events timestamp on a remote server to get around this. where the user has no control over the time.

Comment: Yes.i am also confused about how this feature can be implemented..I had  left a comment on the question.

Comment: like i said, thats not what the question is about. it is an after thought and another question. but it appears that most game companies would store all the events on their own servers and verify the time passed since an event on their end to get around this.